# Process starts itself with different parameters, but they were ignored

Tags: c#

I wrote a Console Application that I start with parameters in the following way

```
ABC.exe -oldParam
```

Inside the application I elaborate the parameters and then want to start the same application with different parameters:

```
string parms = "-newParam";
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ABC.exe", parms); 
proc.WaitForExit();
```

The weird thing is, that the new process starts always with the `"-oldParam"` (the parameters of the 'parent' proccess) instead of `"-newParam"`, regardless what I write into `string parms`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: _"the new process starts always with the "-oldParam""_ - please show how you determined that. Command line arguments are not inherited through `Process.Start()`, the problem probably lies in your code or your debugging skills.

Comment: Hi CodeMaster, sorry you where right! The parameters where set in a hidden part of the code! found it in this second! Thank you anyway!

Comment: @frave You may want to answer your own question then with piece of code that caused you trouble, so others who will have similiar problem will find a solution here.